# Is it possible to control amazon alexa with api(without voice commands)?

Tags: ios, swift, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

i'm developing app in iOS...i have smart home bulb device and also amazon alexa echo dot...i have created the skill on alexa cloud for turn on and turn off the smart home bulb device...its good working with the alexa echo dot.

but i just wanted to know that is there any way to manage the turn on and turn off bulb device via alexa api with my app.?

**like just send text commands to the alexa api and alexa will turn on the my device through my app.i don't want to use voice service**

Thank you

Comment: What is API documentation says? Check amazon alexa app

Comment: api documentation doesn't say anything about this...and alxa app have this functionality..but this app is also record voice and then control the smart device

Comment: Amazon alexa app working great with all devices without voice

Comment: that's i know....i'm asking for api

Comment: `{
        "header": {
            "messageId": "01ebf625-0b89-4c4d-b3aa-32340e894688",
            "name": "TurnOnRequest",
            "namespace": "Alexa.ConnectedHome.Control",
            "payloadVersion": "2"
        },
        "payload": {
            "accessToken": "[OAuth token here]",
            "appliance": {
                "additionalApplianceDetails": {},
                "applianceId": "[Device ID for Your Light Bulb]"
            }
        }
    }`    this request to turn on device

Comment: You can directly send the response to your server from your app and then update Alexa about the state changes. If you have included Display category and Capability you will be able to control the device using Alexa app under "Devices" section . More info here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/connect-a-color-changing-light-bulb-to-alexa.html